# compiled Regex template with passing value dynamically

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, boost-regex

my regex is `(\[((?!attr1)[^\]])*\])` and want to make it a compiled template and pass the "attr1" part dynamically.

input string `root/element1/element2[@attr1='abc']/element3[attr2='xyz']/element4/element5[attr3='pqr']/element6/element7`

Want to pass the attr1, attr2, attr3 dynamically to the regex template and trying to work with one regex object for performance reasons. can you please help me?

Comment: `(\[((?!attr[0-9]*)[^\]])*\])`

Comment: attr values are dynamic values and can be anything

Comment: (\[((?![^=]*)[^\]])*\])

Comment: Why not construct your Regex string dynamically? `string reg = string.Format(@"(\[((?!{0})[^\]])*\])", aatr1);`